# Validations in rails uses meta programming internally? How it actually works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, metaprogramming

We have seen in rails we perform validations on a particular column something like this -
`validates :first_name, presence: true`
what this statement actually do? I think it creates a class method for our Model class with method name - "first_name". This method is called once someone do object.first_name and looks for the value of this parameter, in case if value is empty raises error otherwise returns true.
I am not sure if I am right here. It would be great if some one can please explain this entire cycle. Thank you!

Comment: It checks if first_name attribute is present, before saving the object in the database. It's done once before writing, and isn't used anymore when the object is retrieved.

Comment: validates is a ruby method that ensure that only valid data is saved into your database. You can create your own custom validation as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `validates :attribute, presence: true` line in your model, it relates to an attribute stored in the database and not a custom method.

Your validation will search for the record in your model's table in the database, and ensure the first_name attribute is not nil.

EDIT: As mrzasa pointed out below it doesn't actually retrieve a new instance of your record on validation but uses the attributes currently in memory

If it is it will add a validation error to your record and you will be unable to save it.

I'd strongly suggest reading through https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validations-overview if you want to know how the validations work.

Comment: One clarification - validation doesn't reach to the DB, it validates attributes of a model object in memory.